# Input/output parameters are not visible when executing procedure in SQL navigator

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-navigator

When I execute my stored procedure in SQL Navigator 7.2.0, the input parameters are not shown. There is nothing wrong with the stored procedure.

Is there any configuration to add up? An answer would be really helpful.

Below is how it shows when I execute the stored procedure, where I can't add any parameters and check the output values of the procedure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution where you need to add a configuration at the start of a session. 
*Below are the steps*

1. Close all the sessions from your SQL navigator. `Session-> Close all`
2. Open SQL navigator and open a session and get the Login window. 
   (Either you can open a session and login `Session -> New Session`
3. Then untick the `Enable using DBA view` check box as below
   [image]
4. Then login with credentials and now you can execute procedures with input/output parameters.